# Self-made slideToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been using `slideToggle()` and I love the effect. How does this `slideToggle()` work and how do I recreate it using CSS + Javascript? How does it give the sliding effect as I can't simply just play with `height: 0` and `height: auto`?

Answer (score 1):

you can using `addClass()`

//CSS

```
.new-height {
 //your-css
}
```

//JS

```
$( ".your-class" ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".your-class").slideToggle().addClass('new-height');
});
```